# Fourier Transform 2D artifact - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, fft

So currently I'm trying to wrap my head around the fourier transform (in 2D). I wanted to fourier transform an image and return back in only the magnitude spectrum just like this topic on this site:

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16995/image-reconstructionphase-vs-magnitude

However my image (using spyder ide) comes out like this with some weird artificant in the middle, using the same image from the link above.

original image:

[image: original image]

Magnitude spectrum:

[image: Magnitude spectrum]

The code that I'm using is in python using numpy (np), OpenCV and Matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join


image1 = cv2.imread("Images/test2.png", 0)
fourier = np.fft.fft2(image1)
magnitude = abs(fourier)
inverse = np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.ifft2(magnitude))
plt.subplot(), plt.imshow(np.uint8(inverse), cmap='gray')
plt.title(''), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Update: added imports

Comment: The code as given cannot be run since it's missing imports, referencing local data, etc. Please update it so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hello there sorry! I have updated the imports. It's referencing local data but the original image (image link) is the image that I've used to create the magnitude spectrum.

Comment: That looks like an artifact caused by wrapping of large values. Why do you convert to `uint8`?

Comment: @kazemakase I did that because the fourier transform returns a complex number and in order to reconstruct an image back I needed to transform it to its orginial format (which was uint8).

Comment: Have you checked if the values of `inverse` actually fit in a 8 bytes integer? (I bet they don't.) Try to make your life easy and cast to `np.float64` instead. Also think about if you really want to discard the imaginary part.

Comment: mm I tried that as well (to np.float) however that returns a black image with a white dot just like when I use np.abs for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try changing the `np.uint8` to `np.abs`. Since you want clipping above 255 and not modulus you should do something like this:

```
inverse = np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.ifft2(magnitude))
inv = np.abs(inverse)
inv[inv > 255] = 255
plt.subplot(), plt.imshow(inv, cmap='gray')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but, if I change it to np.abs I just get a black image with a white dot in the middle. I'm also already using a rgbgray image (second argument of cv2.imread (0)).

Comment: Corrected my answer. uint8 does not clip values above 255 acts as a modulus. `np.uint8(257)` gives `1`.

Comment: It works! Awesome, thank you so much for you help. I didn't think of this, but it makes sense thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The weird thing in the middle of your plot is large values being wrapped (conversion to uint8 takes the modulus). When not casting, you see only a white dot in the middle. Typically (for a natural images), the DFT has very high magnitudes at the origin, with magnitudes reducing exponentially for higher frequencies.

The best way to display the DFT is to apply a logarithmic transformation to the magnitude:

```
inverse = np.fft.ifftshift(np.fft.ifft2(magnitude))
inverse = np.log(np.abs(inverse))
plt.subplot(), plt.imshow(inverse, cmap='gray')
```